# Number of primes less than or equal to x

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math, primes

## π(x) = Number of primes ≤ x

Below code gives number of primes less than or equal to N

It works perfect for N<=100000,

- **Input - Output Table**

  ```
  |    Input    |   Output      | 
  |-------------|---------------|
  | 10          |     4✔       |
  | 100         |     25✔      |
  | 1000        |     168✔     |
  | 10000       |     1229✔    |
  | 100000      |     9592✔    |
  | 1000000     |     78521✘   |
  ```

  However, π(1000000) = 78498

  ```
  import time
  def pi(x):
      nums = set(range(3,x+1,2))
      nums.add(2)
      #print(nums)
      prm_lst = set([])
      while nums:
          p = nums.pop()
          prm_lst.add(p)
          nums.difference_update(set(range(p, x+1, p)))
          #print(prm_lst)
      return prm_lst


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      N = int(input())
      start = time.time()
      print(len(pi(N)))
      end= time.time()
      print(end-start)
  ```

Comment: Where do you even check for primality? How do you check it?

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan `nums.difference_update(set(range(p, x+1, p))` removes all multiples of p from `set(nums)`, where `nums` is a set of odd numbers.

Comment: Ok. Try to add a few debug `print`s to see what happens to multiples greater than 100 000. I suspect  that at some point some operation fails silently.

Comment: Perhaps you believe that `num.pop()` will remove the **smallest** element from the set, but I don't believe that is guaranteed. The docs for `pop()` say: *Remove and return an arbitrary element from the set.*

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk  Thanks!
`nums.difference_update(p, x+2*p, p)` is now giving correct answer correct answer.

Comment: That change doesn't make any sense to me. Why should that work?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk even I don't  know how but that's just working,
And yes you are right `num.pop()` is really uncertain method to `pop()` the smallest element from the set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is only correct if `nums.pop()` returns a prime, and that in turn will only be correct if `nums.pop()` returns the smallest element of the set. As far as I know this is not guaranteed to be true. There is a third-party module called [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) that provides a SortedSet class that can be used to make your code work with very little change.

```py
import time

import sortedcontainers
from operator import neg


def pi(x):
    nums = sortedcontainers.SortedSet(range(3, x + 1, 2), neg)
    nums.add(2)
    # print(nums)
    prm_lst = set([])
    while nums:
        p = nums.pop()
        prm_lst.add(p)
        nums.difference_update(set(range(p, x + 1, p)))
    # print(prm_lst)
    return prm_lst


if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = int(input())
    start = time.time()
    print(len(pi(N)))
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
```

Comment: This is definately a good one.

Answer (score 1):

You can read from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n/3035188#3035188) the fastest way like below and with this function for `n = 1000000` I find correctly `78498` prime numbers. *(I change one line in this function)*

From:

```
return ([2] + [i for i in range(3,n,2) if sieve[i]])
```

To:

```
return len([2] + [i for i in range(3,n,2) if sieve[i]])
```

Finally:

```
def primes(n):
    sieve = [True] * n
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)//(2*i)+1)
    return len([2] + [i for i in range(3,n,2) if sieve[i]])

inp =  [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]
for i in inp:
    print(f'{i}:{primes(i)}')
```

Output:

```
10:4
100:25
1000:168
10000:1229
100000:9592
1000000:78498
```